# Whats the right place for testhelper-classes? (phpunit/best practise)

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to test my application with PHPUnit. So I have my application-classes and a second tree with test-classes as usual. Now I need for some test a kind of Dummy/Mock-Objects and I want to know where I should place them. Is it a different usecase and it should be place in common lib folder or what is to prefer?

Comment: please review the answers you have been given so far and either accept the one that solved your problem or update and improve your question to point out why none of these solve your problem, so people have a chance to improve their answers. thanks.

Comment: A very good question with good answers. It's a pity !

Answer (score 1):

In the cases where I don't use mock objects but instead create a throw-away subclass for the test case, I name the class with the test case's prefix and place it in the same file after the test case itself.

The test case prefix avoids any chance that the class's name will clash with any real classes, and placing the code in the same file makes it easy to work with the test. If you find that you need to create multiple subclasses for one test case, this is probably a signal that your class does too much.

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function setUp() {
        $this->fixture = new MyClassTest_DoesNothing;
    }
}

class MyClassTest_DoesNothing extends MyClass
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to mirror the file structure of the project I am working on.

```
/project
  app/
  app/models/BankAccount.php
  tests/
    suite/
      app
      app/models/BankAcountTest.php
    mocks
      app/
      app/models/BankAccountMock.php
```

I find doing it this way keeps everything organized. I will put small Mocks or stubs in the Test Case File if I don't intend to reuse them. As was stated in the other comments, most Mocks can be generated by PHPUnit, but sometimes it is easier just to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

There is no suggested place for where to place hardcoded stubs or mocks. I tend to add a folder `_files` whenever I feel the need for specific external resources in the same folder as the test that needs those. But that just me.

**However**, PHPUnit has a built-in mocking framework, so in general you dont need to hardcode your Stubs and/or Mocks. See the

- [chapter on Test Doubles in the PHPUnit Manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html).

**Example 10.2: Stubbing a method call to return a fixed value**

```
class StubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testStub()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->getMock('SomeClass');

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->expects($this->any())
             ->method('doSomething')
             ->will($this->returnValue('foo'));

        // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return
        // 'foo'.
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething());
    }
}
```

An alternative to PHPUnit's Mocking framework would be [Pádraic Brady's Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery), which is inspired by Ruby's flexmock and Java's Mockito

Comment: Ok, my question was not precise enough. I'm working on a little library and some of theses classes are abstract or only usefull if the are extended by application classes. At this point I only want write test for that library, but I need these DummyApplication-classes so I can be sure that all works as expected and I can pass out the tests with my library. Where I leave the dummy classes?

Comment: @Daniel PHPUnit's mocking framework can stub/mock abstract classes as well. Please see [Example 10.12: Testing the concrete methods of an abstract class](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.AbstractClassTest.php)