# What order are phpunit tests executed?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to test a class that has other classes passed to it (dependency injection), which are stored as class properties. (A settings class, for example that is the result of a Factory).

So, in psuedo code, this is what I am dealing with:

```
//Get settings for this user.
$settings = SettingsFactory::GetSettings();

//Create widget that uses settings
$widget = new Widget($settings);
```

Now, obviously, if we refactor code and break SettingsFactory::Getsettings(), the constructor for Widget will fail. But, not necessarily because anything is wrong with Widget.

So, I want to test these components IN ORDER, skipping "later" tests when "early" tests fail.

Consider my current structure for tests:

```
tests\vendor\Settings\SettingsTest.php
tests\vendor\Widget\WidgetTest.php
```

PHPUnit needs to test SettingsTest.php (and have everything pass) before running WidgetTest.php will be meaningful.

I think I need to use @depends, but that seems to be limited to a single class scope.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835607/dependent-tests-between-two-testcase-classes-in-phpunit) seems to hold a piece of the puzzle, but I am not sure how to implement.

How do I write (structure) these tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the big benefits of DI is that you can avoid issues like this, by injecting a mock `$settings` object that behaves the way you want. This gives you a true unit test of Widget without worrying about the implementation details of Settings:

```
$mockSettings = $this->createMock(Settings::class);
$mockSettings->method('someMethod')->willReturn('something');
$widget = new Widget($mockSettings);

// assertions here
```

Comment: This is true, but here's my problem (which is more likely how I am thinking about the problem than a problem with the code or PHPUnit)... If I have three classes that depend on settings, I have to mock settings for each of those classes / tests. Now, when I update settings to change its functionality, I have to go back and change ALL those tests. I should be able to change it in one place and have it be useful in many tests.

Comment: Unit tests should be independent so you're attempting to force something that is bad practice here. Changing the interface of a widely used class *should* have a significant impact on testing the depending classes, as they're depending on that interface. If it's widely reused you can create a reusable mock/stub, or you can wrap the settings factory in a try/catch and mark the test skipped.

Comment: OK, I hear you. So, this means it's common practice to copy / paste code from one test to another? Thought that might be code smell...? Because if I had that in my actual code base, it would be refactored. This is not the case in unit tests?

Comment: Same logic applies as for DRY in your app code really — if you're truly repeating yourself conceptually, you could pull it out into a separate mock/stub of Settings that you can include whenever it's needed in a test. However if each of the dependent classes uses slightly different features of the Settings class, you wouldn't really be repeating yourself.

Comment: OK, so if I am hearing you correctly, I can create "test_includes.php" file that would contain the Test classes that test the settings and config (and also return the instantiated settings class with the mock info in it, and just include() that at the top of the file, and that should be sufficient, correct?

Comment: You could [create a folder of mock classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700009/whats-the-right-place-for-testhelper-classes-phpunit-best-practise), or you could [extend PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html) classes to add a helper method like `getMockSettings` for relevant test cases.